# Object, Control and array

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following code in VB.NET in which it will check for empty textboxes in an array. The code works fine but when I converted the code to C# it will no longer work. What do I miss? Please help.

```
Public Function CheckForEmptyTextBoxes(obj As Object()) As Boolean
    Dim QEmptyTextBox As Boolean
    For Each ctrl As Object In obj
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            If CType(ctrl, TextBox).TextLength = 0 Then
                QEmptyTextBox = True
            Else
                QEmptyTextBox = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return QEmptyTextBox
End Function
```

Code converted to C#

```
public bool CheckForEmptyTextBoxes(object[] obj)
 {
     bool QEmptyTextBox=false;
     foreach (object ctrl in obj)
     {
         if (ctrl is TextBox)
         {
             if ((TextBox)ctrl.TextLength == 0)
             {
                 QEmptyTextBox = true;
             }
             else
             {
                 QEmptyTextBox = false;
             }
         }
     }
     return QEmptyTextBox;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain why it dosnt work

Comment: There are three textboxes. If all of the textboxes have no entries it will return true. When I try to make an entry on the first and last textboxes leaving the second textbox with no entry it will return false.

Comment: Your Vb.Net code should also have the same effect. You want to return true only if all textboxes are empty?

Comment: I would only **cast** objects if they are valueTypes, like `int` or `bool`, but with reference types I would use the `as`operator `ctrl as TextBox`

Comment: @Ferus7 the `as` operator do cast...

Comment: @Zohar Peled [check](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/08/whats-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators/), what I mean

Comment: The VB code is garbage to begin with. It checks every `TextBox` but the value it returns will only ever be for the last one. There's nothing wrong with your conversion. It's garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @Ferus7 Always good to read Eric's blog. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use that `QEmptyTextBox` variable then you should exit the loop as soon as you set it to `True`. Alternatively, do away with the variable altogether and simply return `True` when you find an empty `TextBox` and then return `False` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Well, that's a bit more blunt that I would put it, but it's correct...

Comment: Even easier, use a LINQ query: `Return obj.OfType(Of TextBox)().Any(Function(tb) tb.TextLength = 0)`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, blunt is my specialty. ;-)

Comment: This is a debugging problem that is off topic and the function is wrong...

Comment: Or the c# version of the LINQ: `return obj.OfType<TextBox>().All(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text));`  Perhaps it's better to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think it should be `All`, not `Any`. The OP wrote "If all of the textboxes have no entries it will return true."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current code actually check if the *last* `TextBox` in the collection is empty:

```
     ...
     if (ctrl is TextBox)
     {
         if ((TextBox)ctrl.TextLength == 0)
         {
             QEmptyTextBox = true;  // <- please, notice absence of "break"
         }
         else
         {
             // this assigment can well overwrite empty TextBox found
             QEmptyTextBox = false; 
         }
     }
     ...
```

To amend your current code:

```
 public bool CheckForEmptyTextBoxes(object[] obj) {
   foreach (object ctrl in obj) {
     TextBox box = ctrl as TextBox;

     if ((box != null) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text)))
       return true; // <- Empty TextBox found
   }  

   // We've scanned the entire collection and no empty TextBox has been found
   return false;
 }
```

If you want to check if there's *at least one* empty `TextBox` you can try *Linq*

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static bool CheckForEmptyTextBoxes(System.Collections.IEnumerable collection) {
  return collection
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .Any(textBox => string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text));
}

...

if (CheckForEmptyTextBoxes(myPanel.Controls)) {
  // If there's an empty TextBox on myPanel 
}
```

Comment: That code wont compile, whats the return type for `CheckForEmptyTextBoxes`¿

Comment: @Codexer: I'm sorry for the typo, the reurn type is `bool` for sure

Comment: I know it is ;)... thanks for the update.